# autoload specific module during testing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test-environments

i noticed my controller test started growing too large, so i moved some stubbing methods into a separate module.

i put it in test/lib/my_module.rb

```
module MyModule
  def mymethod
  end
end
```

so my controller test in test/controllers/my_controller.rb now looks this way:

```
class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include MyModule
  def test_something
  end
end
```

i then tried making rails autoload path "test/lib" during tests only.
for this, i added following lines in config/environments/test.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/test/lib"]
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{config.root}/test/lib"]
```

but when i run my tests with "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake test", it throws:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant MyControllerTest::MyModule
```

if i put same two lines in config/application.rb, everything works well. but i dont want to load this module f.ex. in production.

so why does it happen and how do i fix it? and what is Rails best practice for keeping test-specific code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I place helpers under `test/support/*.rb` and include it:

`test/test_helper.rb`:

```
# some code here

Dir[Rails.root.join('test', 'support', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  include Auth # <- here is a helper for login\logout users in the test env
  # some code here
```

It's normal practice for share modules with a test specs.